# SQL syntax error from from unicode (\u00B0 for degree) in Grails

Tags: sql, grails, unicode

**SQL ERROR**
Class
    com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException
Message
    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'precision=3, scale=0.0, units='°C' where channel_specification_id=1196' at line 1

**Context**

So this error is entirely related to Unicode as the query works for other units that do not include Unicode characters. The °C is actually a Unicode ° and a char C.

It should be noted at one point it was accepting the Unicode ℃ \u2103. Additionally the db is storing these Unicode characters already, and returning the characters to grails upon query but it fails when grails attempts  to update the db with any of these characters.

I have tried setting useUnicode=true, characterSet=UTF-8, adding custtumm dialects etc, and the db is set to use UTF-8 general ci as per similar questions and answers on stackoverflow, none work.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

So the issue, which should have been glaringly obvious was precision! Its a key word, so we escaped the field (`precision`) in the domain class under mapping.